# Blank default in select from a database with php is not showing

Tags: php, sql, select

I try to display me database username with a blank default option. My problem is that my default option is not showing up.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","demo","xxxxx");
mysql_select_db("demo");

$first = 0;
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT vorname FROM users WHERE dispo=1"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){ 
$select= '<select name="select">';
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    if (first == 0){
        $select.='<option value='' selected="selected"></option>';
        $first++;
    }else{
        $select.='<option value='.$rs['vorname'].'>'.$rs['vorname'].'</option>'; 
    }
  } 
} 
$select.='</select>'; 
echo $select;  
?>
```

I'm pretty new to php and database, so I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed it to always add a default blank option if there are records from the result, then it adds all records as options.

What you had was replacing the **first** record with the default option.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT vorname FROM users WHERE dispo=1"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)) { 
$select= '<select name="select">';
$select.='<option value='' selected="selected"></option>';
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
   $select.='<option value='.$rs['vorname'].'>'.$rs['vorname'].'</option>'; 
} 
$select.='</select>'; 
echo $select;  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change below two lines

```
if ($first == 0){ // from if (first == 0){
// and
$select.='<option value="" selected="selected"></option>';
// from $select.='<option value='' selected="selected"></option>';
```

Comment: I changed it. I still have no blank default. When I open the page source code I got this: <select name="select"><option value=Chrissy>Chrissy</option><option value=Christian>Christian</option></select>

Comment: @Mehedi_PSTU I guess it was a cashing problem. Now it is showing. The problem now is that it replaces the first person with the blank field.